# Ошибка получения времени

Tags: python, python-3.x, время, datetime

В моей программе написанной на питоне есть необходимость получения времени. Я использовал такой код:

```
import datetime
offset = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=3))
time=str(datetime.datetime.now(offset))
```

На моем ПК программа верно выводит время со смещением 3, но при переносе программы на другой компьютер там выводится время как будто  hours=10.

Пример: У меня на ПК выводится так:

```
2019-04-20 20:16:49.297578+03:00
```

На другом ПК:

```
2019-04-21 03:16:57.505614+03:00
```

Как исправить данную проблему?

Comment: А в операционной системе на том компьютере время показывается какое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать такой вариант (только не используйте имя `time`, оно пересекается с именем стандартного модуля):

```
import datetime
curr_time = str(datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).astimezone())
print(curr_time)
```

---

```
2019-04-20 22:40:01.268673-04:00
```

---

Или вот такой:

```
import time
curr_time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z', time.localtime())
print(curr_time)
```

---

```
2019-04-20 22:44:54-0400
```